# Hadith about "Don't mess with us, and we won't mess with you"?

Tags: hadith, source-identification

I'm trying to find a hadith I heard long ago. It was like, do your own prayers and live peacefully (to mushriks) and don't mess with out prayers. And we won't mess with you. Something like that. I can't remember exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be your looking for this ... http://quran.com/109

> Say, "O disbelievers,
>
> I do not worship what you worship.
>
> Nor are you worshippers of what I worship.
>
> Nor will I be a worshipper of what you worship.
>
> Nor will you be worshippers of what I worship.
>
> **For you is your religion, and for me is my religion.**"

Surat Al-Kāfirūn (The Disbeliever)

May the creator guide us all.